# No me compila un código de POO en C++

Tags: c++, poo

Este es el ejercicio:

> Generar una clase Persona que siga las siguientes condiciones:
>
> Los atributos son:
>
> - Nombre
> - Edad
> - DNI
> - Sexo (H hombre, M mujer)
> - Peso
> - Altura
>
> Generar los siguientes constructores:
>
> - Un constructor por defecto.
> - Un constructor con el nombre, edad y sexo, el resto por defecto.
> - Un constructor con todos los atributos como parámetro.
>
> Definir los métodos para:
>
> - Carga y muestra de los datos miembro.
> - calcularIMC: calcula el índice de masa corporal como (peso en kg/(altura2 en m)),
> - esMayorDeEdad: indica si es mayor de edad.
>
> Realizar un programa principal que haga uso de la clase.

Los errores que me saltan son:

- Primera linea del main :no matching function for call to 'Persona::Persona()'
- Lineas de COUT del main   :no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and ''

Aquí mi código:

````
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Persona{

  private:
      char nombre[6],sexo; //sexo M/F/X
      int dni,edad;
      float peso, altura;

  public:
      void setPersona (char, char, int, int,float,float); //ALL ATRIBUTOS
      char getNombre ();
      int getEdad ();
      char getSexo ();
      int getDNI ();
      float getPeso ();
      float getAltura ();
      Persona(); //Default
      float calcular_IMC ();
      bool esMayorEdad ();
};


Persona::Persona(){ //CONSTRUCTOR DEFECTO
nombre[6]='Ignacio';
edad=18;
sexo='M';
}


void Persona::setPersona (char _nombre, char _sexo, int _dni, int _edad, float _peso, float _altura){  //CONSTRUCTOR CON LOS ATRIBUTOS
nombre[6]=_nombre;
sexo=_sexo;
dni=_dni;
edad=_edad;
peso=_peso;
altura=_altura;

}

char Persona::getNombre (){
 return nombre[6];
}

int Persona::getEdad (){
 return edad;
}

char Persona::getSexo (){
 return sexo;
}

int Persona::getDNI (){
 return dni;
}

float Persona::getPeso (){
 return peso;
}

float Persona::getAltura (){
 return altura;
}

float Persona::calcular_IMC(){
 return peso/(altura*altura);
}

bool Persona::esMayorEdad(){
 return edad>=18;
}


int main()
{
    Persona p1{'Ignacio','M',44805305,18,60.5,1.67};
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<p1.getNombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Sexo: "<<p1.getSexo<<endl;
    cout<<"DNI: "<<p1.getDNI<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<p1.getEdad<<endl;
    cout<<"Peso: "<<p1.getPeso<<endl;
    cout<<"Altura: "<<p1.getAltura<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<p1.getNombre<<endl;
    cout<<"IMC: "<<p1.calcular_IMC<<endl;
    cout<<"Es mayor de edad? "<<p1.esMayorEdad<<endl;
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error de compilación? ¿Qué marca el stack?

Comment: Coloca los errores que te marca el stack. Por lo que veo estas tratando de obtener los atributos de la clase Persona con void en vez de hacerlo con el tipo que debería corresponder.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro ya edite eso de las funciones que no me habia dado cuenta, y tambien puse los errores que me salen en la descripcion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error es por la forma de definir el constructor, el segundo porque te falta la librería `#include<iostream>` y hay algunos errores en la definición de las propiedades y como acceder a sus valores.

Si vas a usar `int` para declarar una variable, deberás usar `int` para acceder a ella. Para setear valores se usa `void`.

De preferencia si usas C++ en vez de usar `char[]` podrías usar `string`. No es obligatorio pero puedes crear un destructor de clase cuando dejes de usar el objeto Persona.

Haciendo algunas correcciones el programa queda de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Persona{

  private:
      string nombre,sexo; //sexo M/F/X
      int dni,edad;
      float peso, altura;

  public:
      void setPersona (string,string, int, int,float,float);
      string getNombre ();
      int getEdad ();
      string getSexo ();
      int getDNI ();
      float getPeso ();
      float getAltura ();
      Persona();
      ~Persona();
      float calcular_IMC ();
      bool esMayorEdad ();
};

Persona::~Persona(){
    cout<<"Se destruye objeto Persona!!"<<endl;
}

Persona::Persona(){ //CONSTRUCTOR DEFECTO
this->nombre="Ignacio";
this->edad=18;
this->sexo="M";
}


void Persona::setPersona (string _nombre, string _sexo, int _dni, int _edad, float _peso, float _altura){  //CONSTRUCTOR CON LOS ATRIBUTOS
this->nombre = _nombre;
this->sexo= _sexo;
this->dni=_dni;
this->edad=_edad;
this->peso=_peso;
this->altura=_altura;
}

string Persona::getNombre (){
 return this->nombre;
}

int Persona::getEdad (){
 return this->edad;
}

string Persona::getSexo (){
 return this->sexo;
}

int Persona::getDNI (){
 return this->dni;
}

float Persona::getPeso (){
 return this->peso;
}

float Persona::getAltura (){
 return this->altura;
}

float Persona::calcular_IMC(){
 return this->peso/(this->altura*this->altura);
}

bool Persona::esMayorEdad(){
 return this->edad>=18;
}


int main(){
    Persona p1;
    p1.setPersona("Ignacio", "M", 44805305, 18, 60.5f, 1.67f);
    cout<<"Nombre: "<< p1.getNombre()<<endl;
    cout<<"Sexo: "<<p1.getSexo()<<endl;
    cout<<"DNI: "<<p1.getDNI()<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<p1.getEdad()<<endl;
    cout<<"Peso: "<<p1.getPeso()<<endl;
    cout<<"Altura: "<<p1.getAltura()<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<p1.getNombre()<<endl;
    cout<<"IMC: "<<p1.calcular_IMC()<<endl;
    cout<<"Es mayor de edad? "<<endl;
    if(p1.esMayorEdad()){
        cout<<"Si, es mayor de edad"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"No, aun no es mayor de edad"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Donde:
Se accede al valor de la propiedad de la siguiente forma:

```
float Persona::getPeso (){
 return this->peso;
}
```

En vez de:

```
float Persona::getPeso (){
     return peso;
}
```

Conviene crear un destructor de clase el cual tendrá el mismo nombre del constructor:

```
Persona();
 ~Persona();
```

Una vez que finalice el programa se destruirá el objeto.

Salida del programa:

```
Nombre: Ignacio
Sexo: M
DNI: 44805305
Edad: 18
Peso: 60.5
Altura: 1.67
Nombre: Ignacio
IMC: 21.6931
Es mayor de edad? 
Si, es mayor de edad
Se destruye objeto Persona!!
```

Espero te sirva de algo la explicación.

Comment: Que me sirva de algo la explicacion? ME SUPEER SIRVIÓ!!! ENTENDI TODO! te agradezco un monton!! El unico detalle que no me quedo del todo claro es cual sería la funcion del THIS ->

Comment: this es una palabra clave reservada que referencia al objeto (instancia) actual  basado en la clase.  **this->** equivale a decir **en esta instancia**, y luego le sigue, la propiedad  o atributo que deseas accesar. Solo se puede utilizar en métodos dentro de la definición de la clase.

Comment: **this** hace que puedas modificar los datos de la instancia. En realidad es un parámetro implícito. Suponte que en lugar de tener la función `int getEdad()` tienes fuera de la clase una función `int getEdad(Persona * const this)`. Esa es la forma en que lo implementa C++. Guarda la dirección de memoria de la instancia en un puntero llamado **this**. Quizás el `const` te confunda. Ubicado después del asterisco significa que no puedes cambiar la dirección a la que apunta el puntero.

Answer (score 0):

Fernando Carraro, muy buena tu respuesta pero no es necesario utilizar el "this" en este caso. Sugiero que se cambie el atributo dni a string al igual que su método de acceso (método get), puesto que si pongo el valor (en el caso de Cuba el dni tiene 11 dígitos) 00052478945, es una persona nacida el 24 de mayo del 2000. Aquí el tipo de dato int tomaría ese valor como 52478945, eliminando los ceros, y esto es un valor erróneo de dni.

Saludos

Comment: Esto parece más una reseña a la otra respuesta. Sé que aún no tienes el puntaje requerido pero esto podría ir como comentario. También puedes editar la respuesta para que responda directamente la pregunta en forma completa, como lo consideres adecuado. Si aún no sabes cómo responder bien, sugiero que leas [answer].